# Connecting to a data stream with Python

Tags: python, c++

I need to connect to a data stream written in C++ with my current program in Python, any advice or resources on how to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has a `native` keyword that allows functions from c++ to be brought into java as methods. Python might have the same feature.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look through the docs